# MySQL database performance

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, laravel

I am working on a project with PHP/Laravel and MySQL, I have a table that has about 20 columns, and in most cases some of columns are empty... performance of application is important for me, and size of Database is not... I want to know impact of empty columns in my application performance.

Comment: NULL columns have very little impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a huge difference between an `empty/blank` database column and `NULL` value column. As you explained that it is a **empty** column in most cases, there is a chance of low performance, because the database needs more and more space to accommodate all the empty values than a NULL Value. More space means more hardware cost + difficult to maintain + less performance.

So the best way is to set the column type to `NULL` where the database completely ignores the field, use less space and then thereby high performance if you have a large number of records and columns.

Note: As I mentioned, this will only affect unless you have a huge load of data, it won't affect if the number of records are comparatively less.

Answer (score 2):

this Is a very broad question so a specific answer may not be possible.  I wanted to provide an answer however because this sort of question comes up and it can get a standard answer of reference.

In general when thinking of a design, "I want it to perform well" should not be your first question.  You should design your database according to good design principles first (particularly as a beginner!) and then solve performance problems as they come up.  Then as you get experience there you may find a few cases where specific optimizations will be needed.  In other words, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

The standard good db design principles will give you a database which is well optimized for general cases but maybe not for specific cases.  In virtually all cases, you will get good enough performance by going this direction, however.

Foreseeing specific performance problems in an RDBMS that a design cannot accommodate is extremely difficult so you are better off keeping doors open at first and closing only later when you have to.  Otherwise you will probably close the wrong doors and overall harm the performance of your application.

This is good general advice for a beginner regarding performance and design regardless of the database in question.